# How to change setPointFillStyle for LightningChart after adding PointSeries?

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I am adding the series to the chart like this

```
        const series = this.chartInstance
           .addPointSeries({ pointShape: shapes[shapeIndex], dataPattern: lsjs.DataPatterns.horizontalProgressive })
           .setPointFillStyle((solidFill) => solidFill.setColor(lsjs.ColorHEX(palette.simpleSet[seriesColorIndex])))
           .setName(groupTag.slice(0, groupTag.indexOf('(')));
```

I have grid that displays the series name and symbol.
On selecting the row from grid I want to hide the series with particular symbol(example circle) from chart.
Can you please suggest a solution to achieve this on row selection(show series) and deselection(hide series) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our [Simple Scatter Interactive Example](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0001-simpleScatter.html) we show how this can be achieved. You can view and edit the code by clicking on the *Edit this Example*-button.